# Background call receiving in using IMSdroid voip

Tags: android, sip, voip, imsdroid

Thanks in advanced, I am using imsdroid library in my app. calling feature work fine, but i am unable to receive call when app is closed.When I minimize application it works but when i clear application from recent app it can't receive call. What is solution for this issue, please help me out. or provide some reference links.

Comment: You will need to create and keep a background service running to be able to receive calls when the app is closed. Because when an app is closed it is closed. Your code is parked.

Comment: I am also aware of this, but i am talking about imsdroid library. in it, we will not handle the session on background.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, IMSdroid does not provide this functionality. You have to open your application while dealing with them. I got same issue:

https://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/issues/detail?can=2&q=491&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&id=491

Comment: yes @nik , i resolved the problem. and now work fine.

Comment: can u share with me?

Answer (score 0):

finally resolved it with some customization. 
@nik u r right. it is not possible to keep registered all the time.in that case u have to notify the second person when first client tries to make him a call ,and when second client will get notification, then fire a broadcast to start the NativeService. this will register the device. and finally u will get the incoming call.